# Http error 404 in servlet: No webpage was found for the web address

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0

`PrintNamesServlet.java`:

This servlet prints the entered name of the user.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "PrintNamesServlet")
public class PrintNamesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Ram Dhakal");
    }
}
```

**`CounterServlet.java`:**
Counts the number of hits or visit in the page

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException; import
javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; import
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; import
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; import
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "CounterServlet") public class CounterServlet
extends HttpServlet {
    int totalHits;
    public void init() throws ServletException{
        totalHits = 0;
         }
         protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Total visit count: " + totalHits++);
    }  public void destroy(){
           }
           }
```

**`web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PrintNamesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>PrintNamesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PrintNamesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PrintNamesServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CounterServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>CounterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CounterServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CounterServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am getting error:

```
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/
```

As, I am trying to run the servlet for the first time, I am not getting what is wrong with my code. I typed `http://localhost:8080/PrintNamesServlet` in the url.

Comment: user '/' before servlet name in @webservlet annotation

Comment: @WebServlet("/CounterServlet") didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have used Servlet 3.0 specification 
Lets takes look at it

In Servlet 3.0, servlet metadata can be specified using @WebServlet

```
@WebServlet(name="mytest", 
 urlPatterns={"/myurl"}) 
public class TestServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet { 
 .... 
}
```

In this way the servlet is accessed by using the url pattern specified in the annotation.

```
   @@WebServlet(name="mytest",urlPatterns={"/myurl"})
```

according to that servlet is acceseed using

```
  http://localhost:8080/myurl
```

In you case you have only specified name you have to specify urlPatterns also, so you can able to call you servlet properly.

```
  @WebServlet(name = "CounterServlet",urlPatterns={"/CounterServlet"}) public class CounterServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

And you do not need to use web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use annotations like this `@WebServlet(name = "PrintNamesServlet")` the `web.xml` mapping is not used.

You have to either remove these annotations or add `urlMapping` attribute to them.